# Converting CloudFront access logs to Parquet format

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

What is the best way to convert CF access logs to parquet format and write it back to S3.

Currently I know of two common ways:

- Trigger lambda on original log write to s3 and send it to AWS Kinesis
  Firehose for conversion
- Using [CTAS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/ctas.html) periodically to convert an entire table

Which option should I use and what are the main differences between them?

Comment: What is your use case for the converted files? Why Parquet? To give you an idea why this is important, _one possible goal_ would be to efficiently support analysis. In which case, larger files would be better, and the Firehose solution wouldn't be the best choice (because it produces relatively small files).

Answer (score 0):

For the ease of use: Glue crawler
Next thing in-line I can think of is glue job, then the more controlled approach would be emr spark cluster job for faster processing.
ECR/Kubernates are also brings a good argument.